# Can I convert string from DB to vie Attributes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js

I'm getting this string from MongoDB:

> "message": "This candidate is requesting permission to message with
> you, click here to <a href="#" @click.prevent="acceptInv">accept<
> /a> and view the message or <a href="#">reject< /a>",

How can I render this message on the website to be recognized by VUEJS.

[image: This is what comes up in the console.]

Answer (score 0):

You can render using `v-html` directive

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data() {
        return {
          title: "Vue 2 app",
          message: `This candidate is requesting permission to message with you, click here to <a href='#' @click.prevent='acceptInv'>accept</a> and view the message or <a href="#">reject</a>`,
        };
      },
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <div v-html="message">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Thanks for responding!

Comment: it should work..Please share more details.

Comment: I added a snapshot of what appears in the console

Comment: that looks good to me.. how it looks in page?

Comment: the vue attributes shouldn't show... Also when I click the function doesn't get called.

Comment: So, it renders as expected. not sure how can we control what to show and what not to show....function has to be present in component to be get called.